# Modeless dialogs and accelerators

Tags: c++, windows, dialog, accelerator, modeless

I want to perform some action when the user presses `CTRL+S` inside a modeless dialog.
Accelerators would be perfect for this, except that I don't have control over the thread's message loop (think plugin), so I can't call `TranslateAccelerator`.

A nested message loop is not an option because the main application does a lot of processing in between calls to `PeekMessage`.

- Is there some way I can 'force' the existing message loop to handle my accelerator?
- Is there any other way besides accelerators to catch `CTRL+S`?

I thought about using a Window hooks on `WH_GETMESSAGE`, which gets called before returning from `GetMessage` or `PeekMessage`. But I'm not sure what would happen after I successfully called `TranslateAcellerator`, I can't let the application know I handled it.
`WH_MSGFILTER` would require the app to implement a call to `CallMsgFilter`, which it doesn't from a quick glance with a debugger.

My last idea was subclassing the control which is what I'm trying to avoid. That would require some mechanism to signal the keypress event to the parent window, which I don't think is a great design. Also, if I add more controls I would have to subclass every single one.

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fairly infamous interop problem, it rears its ugly head also when using Winforms to implement UI in a native program.  Microsoft's recommendation is a rough-and-tumble one: start your own thread to display the window so you can pump your own message loop.  You'll need SetParent() to avoid Z-order problems.  Scary stuff, do consider a modal dialog thrice before committing to this.

Comment: The bad thing is that the plugin interface is not threadsafe so I would end up deep inside synchronization issues. I've been down that road once and pretty much eliminated it from the get-go, it simply isn't worth it just for a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Good, you thought twice about it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use WM_GETDLGCODE? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645425(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: As I said, I could subclass the control and then handle WM_CHAR (it returns DLGC_WANTALLKEYS on WM_GETDLGCODE) so that should be possible. But it's not an optimal solution and would require subclassing every other child control if I want the shortcut to work in the whole dialog.

Comment: Fair enough.  Could you put a detour in getmessage?  Little bit nasty though for a plugin to do this...

Comment: Actually that's just what WH_GETMESSAGE is for. The trouble is that I don't know if it's safe if I handle the incoming message and then the main application still calls TranslateMessage and DispatchMessage. Maybe I should be detouring these two, but then how do I know the APIs were called from the main loop, not some other modal message loop?